# Working around a very heavy encryption algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, encryption

I'm in the progress of building an API in NodeJS. Our main API is built in Java in which all the ids are encrypted (one example being AA35794C728A440F).

The Node API needs to use the same encryption algorithm for compatibility.

During testing of the API, I was surprised to find that it was only able to handle somewhere in the region of 25 to 40 (depending on the AWS EC2 instance I tested with) requests per second, and that the CPU was maxing out.

Digging into it, I found the issue was with the algorithm being used, specifically that it was performing 1000 md5 operations per key per encrypt/decrypt.

Removing the encryption gave me a massive increase in throughput, up to 1200 requests per second.

I'm stuck with the algorithm - it won't be possible to change without impacting many consumers of the API, so I need to find a way to work around it.

I was wondering what the most efficient way to handle this would be, keeping in mind that I need to be able to 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'?

My question isn't so much how to make the algorithm more efficient, given that I would like to avoid the 1000 md5 ops per id, but rather, an efficient of bypassing the actual encryption itself.

I was thinking of storing all the keys (up to maybe 2 or 3 million) in a map or a tree and then doing a lookup, however that would be mean lugging around 30-50MB of ids in the repository, plus consuming a lot of memory.

Comment: 50MB of memory for cache doesn't sound that much to me... you could also use memcache (possibly AWS ElastiCache) to do the actual caching - this way it can be easily shared across multiple servers...

Comment: It sounds like, lacking any code, that a key derivation is being done on each invocation. Key derivations are designed to be slow. Provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish and some code.

Comment: :) Thanks, that's the issue. The JavaScript implementation of the algorithm did have KDF being done on each invocation. Refactoring to call the KDF once fixed the issue.

Comment: Are you using password based encryption instead of random keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like, lacking any code, that a key derivation is being done on each invocation.

Key derivations are designed to be slow. Provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish and some code.

Comment: But of course expensive key derivations should only be used when you're struck with crappy secrets (human memorable passwords) and not during machine-to-machine communication.

Comment: If machine-to-machine communication use a random key no key derivation is needed.

Comment: 1) You often still use key derivation even if you have random keys, just the cheap key-based variant instead of the expensive password-based variant. For example TLS uses something similar to HKDF to derive several keys from the master secret. 2) The OP's example looks like one where slow key derivation is misguided.

Answer (score 1):

50MB of memory for cache doesn't sound that much to me... you could also use memcache (possibly AWS ElastiCache) to do the actual caching - this way it can be easily shared across multiple servers..